# Making a Magic 8 Ball program in python, what's wrong with this?

Tags: python

```
import time    
import random    
import os     
import sys

os.system('cls')

def randomanswer():

    os.system('cls')
    x = random.randint(0,7)
    if x == 0:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /  FOCUS \\
      /    AND   \\
     /  TRY AGAIN \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 1:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /        \\
      /    YES   \\
     /            \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 2:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        / ARE  \\
       /  YOU   \\
      / CRAZY??? \\
     /   NO!!!!   \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 3:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /   NO   \\
      /          \\
     /            \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 4:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /  LOOKS \\
      /   GOOD   \\
     /            \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 5:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       / BETTER \\
      / NOT TELL \\
     /   YOU NOW  \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 6:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /  YES,  \\
      /          \\
     / DEFINITELY \\
    /______________\\""")

    if x == 7:
        print("""
           /\\
          /  \\
         /    \\
        /      \\
       /  MAYBE \\
      /          \\
     /   SOMEDAY  \\
    /______________\\""")

    y=0
    print("AGAIN?")
    print("""

1. YES
2. NO 

    """)

    y = input(int(""))
    if y == 1:
        guess()
    else:
        print("")


def guess():

    os.system('cls')
    print("ASK ME A QUESTION")
    print("")
    input("")
    time.sleep(1.)
    print("")
    print("TO SHAKE MAGIC 8 BALL PRESS ENTER")
    input("")
    time.sleep(2.)
    randomanswer()

guess()
```

When I run this, get to the end and type 2 (for "no") it reruns the program anyway. Please help.

Comment: Try `y = int(input(""))` instead of `y=input(int(""))`

Comment: `y = input("")if y == "1":`

Answer (score 0):

Your input is wrong (and should raise a `ValueError` rather than give the behaviour you describe). Try

```
y = int(input(""))
```

instead of `y=input(int(""))`: that is, convert the user's (string) input into an integer `y` rather than attempt to convert the empty string into an integer.